# How to recover my code

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I cover one of my visualforce pages' code mistakenly and saved it.How can I recover my original code?Thanks!

Comment: I really doubt that is possible. You have options like recovering it from one of sandboxes or from production(if the code is there) of from version control (if you use one). _Stupid thought: You can just press CTRL+Z in you developer console to recover code._

Comment: From where have you saved the code. Is it Eclipse or any other IDE

Comment: I saved it in salesforce.

Comment: That's why you should use IDE, it atleast remembers local changes

Answer (score 1):

Once saved you can't recover you code on developer console unless the change are done on current tab itself. In that case you can try Ctrl + Z. I would recommend you to use eclipse with git so that you can avoid such issues.

Comment: I have tried to use Ctrl_Z but i didn't work.Thanks for your advice.